# set_difference issues, not returning all values or duplicates

Tags: c++

I am trying to take to arrays and output the integers that don't appear in the first (bag1) and second (bag2) array into a new third (newbag) array.The function is not giving me the correct difference. It also needs to contain any duplicates if one bag has more of a certain number.

My output is missing the duplicates from the list:

```
Bag 1: 1 3 3 4 5 5 7 7 8 9 9 11 12 12 12 16
Bag 2: -100 -4 1 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 9 11 12 12 12 15 19
Difference Bag: -100 -4 6 8 15 19
```

I have tried changing the order order of the bags, but they right numbers never output.

```
const ArrayBag ArrayBag ::operator - (const ArrayBag bag){
    ArrayBag newBag;
    vector<int> diff;
    set_difference(items,items + getCurrentSize(),bag.items,bag.items + 
    bag.getCurrentSize(),
                 inserter(diff,diff.begin()));

    for (int i = 0; i < diff.size(); i++) {
      newBag.add(diff[i]);
    }
    return(newBag);
```

Comment: So the problem is that `Bag 1` has `5` twice while `Bag 2` has `5` once and thus you'd expect the output to also consist of a `5` (once), correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the correct function.  You need [`std::set_symmetric_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference) to get the difference of both sets.  When you used `set_difference` it only copies the elements from the first set that are not found in the second set.  Using `std::set_symmetric_difference` it will copy the elements that don't exists in both sets into a new one.  You can see that with:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 11, 12, 12, 12, 16};
    std::vector<int> v2{-100, -4, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12, 12, 15, 19};

    std::vector<int> v_symDifference;

    std::set_symmetric_difference(
        v1.begin(), v1.end(),
        v2.begin(), v2.end(),
        std::back_inserter(v_symDifference));

    for(int n : v_symDifference)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
}
```

Which outputs

```
-100 -4 5 6 7 8 9 15 16 19
```

You can see it in action in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b69838179a556c36)